# generate 6 numbers between 1 and 2 in a 2:1 ratio in SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

how can i generate 6 numbers between 1 and 2 where 4 of the numbers will be 1 and the other 2 will be 2 in a random order i.e.

### results

1
2
1
1
1
2

and also in a different ratio i.e. 3:2:1 for numbers between 1 and 3 for 12 numbers

i.e.

### results

1
1
2
3
1
2
1
3
1
1
3
3

results don't have to be in this order but in the ratios as above in oracle SQL or PL/SQL

Comment: How did you come up with the number 6 in the first set and 12 in the second question..? is that based on some logic?

Comment: see DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMINTEGER

Comment: Do you need to have exactly 4 1's and 2 2's or do you need to have 6 numbers (1 and 2) which usually conform to the 2/1 ratio? That is, it is OK to have 3 1s and 3 2s because random numbers may produce that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ratios perfect you could do something like this - generate all the numbers, then sort in random order:

```
SELECT r
FROM   (SELECT CASE
               WHEN ROWNUM <=4 THEN 1
               ELSE 2
               END AS r
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6)
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value;

R                      
---------------------- 
2                      
1                      
1                      
2                      
1                      
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in straight SQL; it's horrifically inefficient, and a PL/SQL one might be less so.  It's also completely static; differing ratios call for a different number of values selected.

```
select value
  from (
       select mod(value, 2) + 1 as value, 
              row_number() over (partition by 
                                   case mod(value, 2) = 1 
                                     then 1 
                                     else 0 
                                   end) as twos_row,
              row_number() over (partition by 
                                   case mod(value, 2) = 0
                                     then 1 
                                     else 0 
                                   end) as ones_row
         from (select dbms_crypto.randominteger as value
                 from dba_objects
                order by object_id
              )
       )
 where twos_rows <= 2
    or ones_rows <= 4
```

The inner-most select grabs a big stack of random numbers.  The next query out determines whether that random value would be a 2 or a 1 by mod'ing the earlier random value.  The last level of nesting just filters out all the rows after the correct number of that type of row has been returned.

This is untested and fragile.  If you need a solution that's reliable and performance, I'd recommend PL/SQL, where you

- loop
- pick off random numbers
- determine what partition in your set of values they'd fit into
- keep them if that partition hasn't been satisfied
- exit when all partitions have been satisfied.

Comment: the numbers 6 in the first and 12 in the second were just random numbers i used as an example, they could be any figure as long as conform to the ratios

Comment: the numbers need to be in the ratios, so having 3 1s and 3 2s is not what i want. it can be possible though for the number generation to be 4 2s and 2 1s or vice versa and for the other ratio  - 6 1s 4 3s and 2 1s or any combination that matches the ratio, also the total number can be anything as long as they match the ratio

Comment: for some reason i am not able to use dbms_crypto.randominteger i am using oracle 10.2 but there are certain functions in oracle we are prevented from using. I would be interested in you PL/SQL solution

Comment: Any answer that requires randomization of the order will require dbms_crypto access -- talk to your DBA about getting access to that package.